INVALIDJOB - Weird query parsing error when trying to create a bulk api 2.0 query job
I am using cURL to send the following bulk API query job creation request:
curl https://[...]/services/data/v62.0/jobs/query -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
    -d '{"operation":"query",
         "query":"SELECT Id,AccountId,...,Partnership__c 
                   FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE 'S%' OR Name LIKE 'A%'"}' 

And receive a 400 with the following response:
[{"errorCode":"INVALIDJOB","message":"Query parsing error: unexpected token: '%'"}]

The query works in the developer console as is.
I tried wrapping the where clause in parenthesis, as well as escaping the single quotes in multiple ways, even though I don't think I need to. Can't get this to work, and afaik - this is a simple where clause that should be supported.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

How were you escaping the single quotes? -- note that your -d param starts with a ' and ends with the next ' which just happens to be the LIKE '

Okay, so thanks to @cropredy indeed that was a problem with the quote, I used --data @filename and it worked well, for anybody running into it - don't use all these quotes, rely on a file as input.
Thanks
